# Netsuite Developer Account for User Management AutoProvisioning

Tags: netsuite

I am working on user auto provisioning for my IDP and exploring the NetSuite. I searched over net but couldn't find any credible document. Can anyone please help me regarding

1. How to sign developer account ?
2. REST APIs documentation regarding User Management in the context of Autoprovisoning.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I have some articles that could help you out:

How to sign developer account ?

[How to get a SuiteCloud Developer Network Account | Ursuscode](https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/how-to-get-a-suitecloud-developer-network-account/)

REST APIs documentation regarding User Management in the context of Autoprovisoning. (Not sure exactly what you need but look at the documentation material here:)

[Netsuite Documentation](https://netsuitedocumentation1.gitlab.io/netsuitedocumentation1/)

or if you have access to Netsuite:

[Netsuite Help Center](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl)

Good luck.